# Immortal start and watch process from sh file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have installed [Immortal](http://immortal.run) and I would like to start a script contained in a `.sh` file.

I've tried looking at the docs but I always get a `missing command error`.

This is what I have tried:

```
immortal -l /tmp/play-log.log -logger play.sh
```

With the purpose of starting a `play.sh` script.

This is the usage from `immortal -h`

```
Usage: immortal [-v] [-ctl dir] [-d dir] [-e dir] [-f pidfile] [-l logfile] [-logger logger] [-p child_pidfile] [-P supervisor_pidfile] [-u user] command

command
    The command with arguments if any, to supervise

-c run.yml
     run.yml configuration file
-ctl /var/run/immortal/<service>
    Create supervise directory /var/run/immortal/<service>
-d dir
    Change to dir before starting the command
-e dir
    Set environment variables specified by files in the dir
-f pidfile
    Follow PID in pidfile
-l logfile
    Write stdout/stderr to logfile
-logger command
    A command to pipe stdout/stderr to stdin
-n  No daemon mode, stay in the foreground
-P pidfile
    Path to write the supervisor pidfile
-p pidfile
    Path to write the child pidfile
-r number
    number of retries before program exit
-u user
    Execute command on behalf user
-v  Print version
-w seconds
    seconds to wait before starting
```

Comment: The help says `-logger logger`. You're using `-logger play.sh`. Where's the logger command for `-logger`?

Comment: @muru God, I have no idea what you asked. Is a brand new world for me. (¬_¬”)

Comment: Then why are you using the `-logger` option? O.o

Comment: It was taken from an example in the doc and I thought it was the only solution, like "Ok log whatever I'm doing and run this file"

Comment: Ever example in https://immortal.run/post/immortal/ that uses `-logger` has a command after the `-logger`, for example `-logger "tee /tmp/y.log"`, or `--logger "logger -h 10.0.0.1 -t app"`.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do just to run the file script? `immortal -l /tmp/play-log.log -logger "./play.sh"`?

Comment: `immortal -l /tmp/play-log.log play.sh`, presumably.

Comment: I made sure the script was executable and then I did `immortal -l /tmp/play-log.log play.sh` but it returns nothing and the process does not start :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, being an sh file the solution was:

```
immortal -l ./play-log.txt /bin/sh -c "./play.sh"
```

or without log

```
immortal /bin/sh -c "./play.sh"
```